# asp.net mvc 4 letter from site encoding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have feedback form on my mvc site, I need to send this form to email.
I want to test my form, so I save MailMessage object to disk as *.eml file

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Contacts()
{
    FeedbackForm temp = new FeedbackForm();
    temp.Message = @Resources.Global.Contacts_Form_Message_Field;
    return View(temp);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contacts(FeedbackForm Model)
{    
    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;            
    msg.From = new MailAddress(Model.Email,
                              @Resources.Global.Contacts_Form_Email_Title);
    msg.To.Add("tayna-anita@mail.ru");

    string message = @Resources.Global.Contacts_Form_Name_Field + ": "
                     + Model.Name + "\n"
                     + "Email: " + Model.Email + "\n"
                     + @Resources.Global.Contacts_Form_Phone_Field + ": "
                     + Model.Phone + "\n\n"
                     + Model.Message;
    msg.Body = message;
    msg.IsBodyHtml = false;          

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mysmtphost");
    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.SpecifiedPickupDirectory;
    client.PickupDirectoryLocation = @"C:\test";

    try
    {
        client.Send(msg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    FeedbackForm tempForm = new FeedbackForm();
    tempForm.Message = @Resources.Global.Contacts_Form_Message_Field;

    return View(tempForm);
}
```

and I get:

```
 X-Sender: "Letter from site" <sssssss@mail.ru>  
 X-Receiver: tayna-anita@mail.ru   
 MIME-Version: 1.0   
 From: "Letter from site" <sssssss@mail.ru>  
 To: tayna-anita@mail.ru  
 Date: 21 May 2013 16:57:55 +0400  
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8   
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64   

 TmFtZTogdGVzdCB0ZXNzc3NzdApFbWFpbDogc3Nzc3Nzc0BtYWlsLnJ1ClBob25lOiA4
 OTIwODcxMzA2MQoKW2F1XSBDaG9pY2VzIChjb25maWRlIGluIG1lKSAtIGhhcnZleSB4
 IG1pa2UgW2F1XSBDaG9pY2VzIChjb25maWRlIGluIG1lKSAtIGhhcnZleSB4IG1pa2Vb
 YXVdIENob2ljZXMgKGNvbmZpZGUgaW4gbWUpIC0gaGFydmV5IHggbWlrZQ==
```

Why body of the letter looks in that way ?

I will send letters from site in English and in Russian and I set `msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;`.

What should I do to don't have problems with encoding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is a message encoded with Base-64. You can see this from the email header:

> Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Presumably, you are opening the message in a plain-text editor, so the email content is not being decoded.

If you decode the message using a [Base64 Decoder](http://www.base64decode.org/) (which any email client will do automatically), you get the following:

> Name: test tessssst
>   Email: sssssss@mail.ru
>   Phone: 89208713061
>
> [au] Choices (confide in me) - harvey x mike [au] Choices (confide in
>   me) - harvey x mike[au] Choices (confide in me) - harvey x mike

Comment: So, I'll not have problems with encoding when I will send form to email, right?

Comment: No, that is a very typical format for an email message and will be automatically decoded by any email client.

Comment: Good, thank u. But why my `"\n"`-codes in body of the letter dont work?

Comment: They do - it's just SO's blockquote formatting has stripped them from my answer. If you decode the encoded string via the link provided you'll see that the newlines are there.